# How do I tell Babel CLI to ignore any path with "__" in it?

Tags: node.js, babeljs, glob, babel-cli

```
"@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
```

Seems really simple.

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli#ignore-files

```
 babel src --out-dir lib --ignore "src/**/*.spec.js","src/**/*.test.js"
```

So I set it up like so:

```
babel src --out-dir cjs --ignore "**/_*" --copy-file --watch
```

Glob reference: https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob

But I see this in the output:

```
add:cjs/__mocks__/@xyz/common-fn.js
add:cjs/middleware/__mocks__/uuid.js
```

OK I try this:

```
babel src --out-dir cjs --ignore "**/_+","_+" --copy-file --watch
```

And these:

```
babel src --out-dir cjs --ignore "**/_*/*.*\ --copy-file --watch 
babel src --out-dir cjs --ignore "**/__mocks__/*.*",  --copy-file --watch 
babel src --out-dir cjs --ignore "[src|middleware]/**/__mocks__/*.*" --copy-file --watch"
babel src --out-dir cjs --ignore "**/_+/**/*.*" --copy-file --watch
```

Same result every time. **It really seems like that last one should work:** ignore any path with zero or more directories followed by a directory that has at least one _ in the name, then zero or more directories then a file matching any pattern. Am I reading that right?

Then I tried being very specific:

```
babel src --out-dir cjs --ignore "nes/middleware/__mocks__/*.js", --copy-file --watch
```

And I get:

```
add:nes/middleware/__mocks__/localize.js
```

I can't tell if this is a bug in Babel or me misunderstanding glob patterns.

Comment: Some of your glob patterns are correct and some are incorrect. You can test using [globster.xyz](https://globster.xyz/?q=nes%2Fmiddleware%2F__mocks__%2F*.js&f=nes%2Fmiddleware%2F__mocks__%2Flocalize.js%2Cnes%2Fmiddleware%2Flocalize.js%2Cnes%2Fmiddleware%2Fmocks%2Flocalize.js)

Can you share what is ur directory structure? Is `nes` folder inside `src` ?

Comment: nes folder is not inside src

Comment: Thanks @Domajno [globster helps](https://globster.xyz/?q=**%2F__*%2F**%2F*.js&f=src%2F__mocks__%2F%40co%2Fmex-fn.js%2Csrc%2Fmiddleware%2F__mocks__%2Fuuid.js). I submitted a bug report.

Comment: @Domajno btw globster uses a different glob lib (minimatch) than babel (glob) so the results on globster aren't 100% helpful when it comes to figuring out issues with glob

Comment: I think glob uses minimatch under the hood anyway. That's what it says in [npm package description](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob). Ofc, minimatch provides certain configuration that may vary.

Comment: Good catch, I stopped going down the package.json rabbit hole one level too soon

Comment: @Domajno this appears to be a possible bug in Babel, filed a bug report (with a repo detailing the failure) here https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/9680

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be some debate about [whether Babel fully supports Glob patterns at the CLI level.](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/9680)

I managed to get it working with this ignore pattern:

```
--ignore "src/**/__mocks__/**/*.js" --ignore "src/**/*.test.js"
```

This pattern `**/__*/**` will work in Glob but fails in Babel.